# javascript - Table row not created after second change of text input

Tags: javascript

This is my HTML code:

```
<table id="display_table"><tr>
<td>No. of Questions:&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="text" id="questions_num"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td>No. of Options:&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="text" id="options_num"></td>
</tr></table>
```

I want to make it such that when the user enters *x* in the text input (whose id is `options_num`), *x* rows will be created. For each new row that is created, there should be a left column and a right column. The left column will contain the **"Option" + *somenumber***, where *somenumber* refers to the row that has been created, and the right column will create a text input.

This is what I have tried in my JS:

```
document.getElementById("options_num").onkeyup = function() {
    var options_num = parseInt(document.getElementById("options_num").value);
    var display_text = '<tr><td>No. of Questions:&nbsp;</td><td><input type="text" id="questions_num"></td></tr><tr><td>No. of Options:&nbsp;</td><td><input type="text" id="options_num"></td></tr>'
    for(var i = 1; i <= options_num; i++) {
        display_text += "<tr><td>Option " + i + ":&nbsp;</td><td>" + "<input type='text' id='option_" + i + "'</td></tr>";  
    }
    document.getElementById("display_table").innerHTML = display_text;
    document.getElementById("options_num").value = options_num.toString();
    document.getElementById("options_num").focus();
}
```

And it works when I first enter a value into the text input (whose id is `question_num`), but when I change the value, it does not work (it does not do anything). [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8yYyW/).

So how do I get my JS code to work?

Comment: The problem here is that you are replacing your inputs in the `onkeyup` handler, but the handler is attached to the original input that you are overwriting. jQuery has fairly easy ways to get around this, but you're probably best off not replacing them over and over unless there is a good reason to do so. And you also shouldn't use tables for layout unless there is a good reason. As susheel suggests, just use `div`s, and replace the portion you need to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work after the first time, is that `innerHTML` actually destroys event binding. So after you modify `table.innerHTML` browser completely rebuilds new DOM elements without original `onkeyup` event listener attached.

I would recommend to change HTML a little, it will make everything simpler:

```
<table id="display_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>No. of Questions:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="questions_num"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>No. of Options:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="options_num"/></td>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="rows"></tbody> <!-- append generated HTML here -->
</table>
```

and modified JS:

```
document.getElementById("options_num").onkeyup = function () {

    var options = document.getElementById("options_num"),
        optionsNum = parseInt(options.value),
        tbody = document.getElementById("rows"),
        rows = '';

    for (var i = 1; i <= optionsNum; i++) {
        rows += "<tr><td>Option " + i + "</td><td>" + "<input type='text' id='option_" + i + "'</td></tr>";
    }

    tbody.innerHTML = rows;
    options.focus();
}
```

So the idea is to put table rows into `tbody` and it makes easy adding new and replacing replacing old rows.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8yYyW/2/